# Обработка строки запроса в php

Tags: php

Как превратить некоторые символы в специальный символы понятные браузеру. Помню где-то видел такую стандартную функцию в php, теперь найти не могу. Например в строке запроса встречается пробел то по стандарту его заменить на %20 нужно по моему. Извините за столь унылое объяснение, просто не знаю как нормально объяснить. Но я думаю меня понял:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlencode($str)
```